# Designing a sticker template based on a 3D model

Tags: modeling, 2d

I'm an absolute rookie in Blender, but recently I faced a hands-on challenge. I feel like Blender can help me out with it.

I want to print and cut decals for my gamepad, something like that:

[image: Decal Example]

The gamepad manufacturer has published its exact three-dimensional model:

[image: Model Example]

Is it possible to design a decal template based on this three-dimensional model in Blender? How?

Thank you.

Comment: Is that decal material able to bent or what? Water transfer? Or it is paper and you want to cut a little bit space for bending surface

Comment: If that picture is what you want, using `project from view` and directly design on texture image should be your answer

Comment: @Hikariztw I'm going to print it on a sheet of adhesive vinyl, so it can bend and it can stretch to a moderate extent.

Comment: You can assign some face to a material that use for the sticker. And for UV, you should project from top view with orthogonal camera. Each time you modified the image you should see the effect of it

Comment: @Hikariztw Um, sorry, either I didn't get it, or it's not quite what I am looking for. I want to design a two-dimensional outline of the sticker. Somehow figure out from a three-dimensional model what shape the thing I cut out of the vinyl has to be so that it will stick to certain edges perfectly, bending and stretching at the right places.

Don't know if that's even doable with this kind of a tool, to be honest.

Comment: In other words, I want to figure out the shape of a decal so it can be lasercut. From a 3d model.

Comment: did you found the solution for your problem?